# if multiple checkbox checked, database column updated with 0/1 in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, checkbox

I am trying to update the database by using checkboxes. if i check the check-box the existing column of database will be updated with the 0/1 value. So far i have done using ajax/jquery. 
first problem  is the jquery which i am trying, it only updates the first checkbox of the the whole data and secondly as soon i refresh the page it updates automatically it is updating with the column replacing first row to [BLANK] only. means not showing 0 neither 1. I wonder if i can do with the checkboxes. Its my first try using ajax.
Thanks for consideration!!

**CONTROLLER :**

```
   public function user_status()
 {

 if ( $this->session->userdata('session_status'))
    {
        $this->load->model('admin/admin_user_mngmt_model');
        $reg_id = $this->input->post('reg_id');
        $status = $this->input->post('status');
        $status = $this->admin_user_mngmt_model->update_status($reg_id, $status);
       if($status == true){
              // echo "true";
              $this->load->view('admin_view/admin_user_mngmt/user-management', $status);
       }else{
               echo "false";
         }

        echo "<pre>" ;
        print_r($status);
    }
    else {
        redirect ('admin/admin_control/admin_login');
    }

 }
```

**MODEL :**

```
public function update_status($reg_id, $status)
{

$sql = "UPDATE fw_registeration SET status=? WHERE reg_id=?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql, array($status, $reg_id));

if($result){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}   

}
```

**VIEW :**

**for checkbox :**

```
  <td><input type="hidden" name="user_status_id" class="mycheckbox" id="user_status_id"  value="<?php echo $da['reg_id']; ?>"/>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='user_status' id='user_status' value=''/>
       <p id='user_status_msg'></p>
```

**Jquery :**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function(){

    var link =  "<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
     alert('loaded');
    $(".user_status").prop('checked', true); 


    var status = $(this).val(); 
    var reg_id = $("#user_status_id").val();

    alert(reg_id);
    $.post(link + "admin/admin_control/user_status", {reg_id:reg_id, status:status,  ajax : 1}, function(data){
        alert(data);

    //  if(data == true){
            $("#user_status_msg").html('user is updated.');

    //}

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your jQuery code.

You are executing your whole code inside `$(document).ready`. You should put some code inside the checkboxes' event...

I think you want something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var link =  "<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
     alert('loaded');
    $(".user_status").prop('checked', true); 

    $(".user_status").on("change",function(){
        var status = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0; //testing if is checked... 
        var reg_id = $("#user_status_id").val();
        $.post(link + "admin/admin_control/user_status", {reg_id:reg_id, status:status,  ajax : 1}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know if this is enough for your solution, but we can start with this...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. now, it is working fine with the databases but the problem is it only updating the first row of the column no matter whatever the checkbox i have checked. that's confusing now otherwise the main problem is solved thank you for help.!

Comment: No problem i have done that confusing problem :) anyways thank you so much for the help.